# Unable to add data or is not showing using $_SESSION in shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, session, shopping-cart

I'm creating a shopping cart where there are two web pages; the purchase.php (where you can see all the list of available products and add them to cart) and the cart.php (where you will be able to view all the items you've added and remove an item or clear all the cart, and the total of an item)

This is my code in purchase.php:

```
<?php session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Purchase</title>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="datatable-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="datatable-bootstrap.js"></script>

    <?php
    require('config/db_conn.php');


    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") or die(mysql_error());





    if(!empty($_POST["add"])) {
                $productByCode = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE p_code='" . $_POST["p_code"] . "'");
                $itemArray = array($productByCode["p_code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode["p_name"], 'code'=>$productByCode["p_code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["p_price"]));

                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    if(in_array($productByCode["p_code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                                if($productByCode["p_code"] == $k)
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                }
            } 


    ?>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
    background-color: #6BBEE4;
    }

    th
    (
    text-align:center;
    )

    td
    (
    align:center;
    )

    .text-center
    {
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    img
    {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .hide
    {
        visibility: none;
    }

    .quantitySize
    {
        width: 90px;
    }

    .pull
    {
        margin-left: 220px;
        margin-top: -360px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    </style>
    <body>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
      <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php" >MyComputer</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="purchase.php">Purchase</a></li>     
            <li><a href="cart.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>





            <?php while($result=mysql_fetch_array($fetch))  { ?>
            <div class="well form-container-">
                <form method = "post" action="cart.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $result['p_code']?>">
                    <div class="form-group"><img src="<?php echo $result['p_image']?>"></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><?php echo $result['p_name']?></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><?php echo $result['p_code']?></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><?php echo $result['p_price']?></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><input class="quantitySize" type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" value="Add to Cart"></div>
                </form>
                <form class="pull">
                <div class="form-group"><p><?php echo $result['p_desc']?></p></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This one is for my cart.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['username']=="")
    {
    header("location: login.php");
    }

    if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
    switch($_GET["action"]) {
        case "add";
    if(!empty($_POST["add"])) {
        $productByCode = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE p_code='" . $_POST["p_code"] . "'");
        $itemArray = array($productByCode["p_code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode["p_name"], 'code'=>$productByCode["p_code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["p_price"]));

        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode["p_code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($productByCode["p_code"] == $k)
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
    } 
break;
        case "remove":
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                            unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                            unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                }
            }
        break;
        case "empty":
            unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        break;  
    }
    }
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>MyCart</title>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <style type="text/css">

    body
    {
    background-color: #6BBEE4;
    }

    </style>
    <body>




    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
      <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php" >MyComputer</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.php">Purchase</a></li>     
            <li class="active"><a href="cart.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="shopping-cart">
    <div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart <input class="pull-right" type="button" name="empty" value="Empty Cart"></div>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
        $item_total = 0;
    ?>  
    <table class="table table-striped datatable " id="example" border="1" >
                <thead align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Product Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Image</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Code</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Description</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $item['p_name']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="<?php echo $item['p_image']?>"></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $item['p_code']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $item['p_desc']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo "$" .$item['p_price']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type = "button" class="btn btn-primary" name="remove" value="Remove"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        $item_total += ($item['p_price']*$item["quantity"]);
                    } ?>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>        
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
    </div>
    </head>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I click the "Add to Cart" button, I got redirected to my cart.php but the items are not showing. I'm afraid my codes for the session for my cart are incorrect but I don't know how to fix this

PS Let's just forget about the SQL injection for the time being as well as the PDO and Mysqli_function. I just need to focus on mysql_function for now. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Did you set session_start() on top of your file? And what is the result of var_dump($_SESSION['cart_item']);die; ?

Comment: @MHakvoort .,I've forgotten to include the session_start() but I've edited it now yet stil the items are not showing. By the way I'm not familiar with the var_dump.

Comment: it seems you call session which was not defined in purchased.php, check again

Comment: @JeanGkol will you please elaborate? Thanks. By the way I've already set the session_start() on top of my purchase.php

Comment: pls see first your HTML structure. it makes me confused to answer.
<style> should be placed above tag </head> and place the PHP script inside tag </head> to below tag<body> or below session_start(). Here, you I didn't see <body> tag :( . then try to run it again

Comment: you can place PHP script above tag <!DOCTYPE html>, inside <body> tag or even below close tag </html>
But, inside tag <head></head> is really not good practice

Comment: @JeanGkol tried everything you've suggested. I'm now getting undefined index on my cart.php. Anyway sorry for the late response, I was busy making my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have executed `session_start();` in all files that use the session.  Add it to the top of your `purchase.php`, or put it in another file and require it in both files.

Your form in `purchase.php` is posting to `cart.php`, so this code in `purchase.php` will not be run:

```
if(!empty($_POST["add"])) {
//code
}
```

Comment: i've edited that now but still the items are not yet showing.

Comment: i've transferred the code `if(!empty($_POST['add'])) to my cart.php now but I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\user\cart.php on line 13

Comment: I've updated the codes and have fixed the error I've mentioned but I'm getting another error like this: `
Notice: Undefined index: p_price in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\user\cart.php on line 115  . I'm getting an undefined index of those kind. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That means that p_price doesn't exist in $item. Try to dump $item to see what is in it.